# Maclaurin Series by derivatives

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, binomial-coefficients

I know that the Maclaurin series expansion for 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$ using binonmial coefficients is:

= 1 - $\frac{x^2}{2}$ + $\frac{3x^4}{8}$ - $\frac{5x^6}{16}$ + $\frac{35x^8}{128}$ + O(x^9)

However, when I try to use derivative rules, evaluating at a = 0, I get

f(0) = 1

f '(x) = $\frac{2x}{-2(1+x^2)^(3/2)}$  which = 0 at when a = 0

All other derivatives have x in the numerator, which also give coefficients of 0.

As a result, the Maclaurin series using derivatives would be:

1 + 0 + 0 + 0....

Why is this the case?  I would expect that the Maclaurin series using binomial coefficients matches the Maclaurin series obtained by taking derivatives.

Comment: Check [here.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=derivative+x%2F(1%2Bx%5E2)%5E(3%2F2))

Comment: It might be easier to find series for $(1+x)^{-1/2}$ first, and then plug in $x^2$.

Comment: That's actually how I got the first expansion I showed.  What I'm trying to figure out is why using Method 1 (binomial expansion using x^2) gives a different result than using derivatives where the coefficients cn = $\frac{f^n(a)}{n!}$   where a = 0

Comment: It does not. Have you checked the link? $f''(x)$ does not vanish at $x=0$.

Comment: Oh, I  missed the link.  Now I see that every other term disappears, which makes sense with x^2.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your derivatives again.

They are not all zero at a=0.

For example when you find your f''(x) using quotient rule, the derivative of the top will generate a non-zero value at a=0.

Comment: Got it - thanks!